# JPA with Jboss Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, jboss

### How to resolve this Exception??

Can someone please let me know the reason why i'm getting this exception:

Configuration:

```
           jdk1.6
           Jboss4.2
           JPA provider: OpenJpa
           EclipseIDE
```

Complete stack Trace:

```
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:323)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:338)
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ProductDerivations.reportErrors(ProductDerivations.java:380)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ProductDerivations.load(ProductDerivations.java:283)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.populateConfiguration(Configurations.java:357)
at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCEnhancerAgent.registerClassLoadEnhancer(PCEnhancerAgent.java:165)
at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCEnhancerAgent.premain(PCEnhancerAgent.java:145)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.toOpenJPAProperties(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:477)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.toOpenJPAProperties(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:359)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation.load(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:541)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation.load(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:360)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ProductDerivations.load(ProductDerivations.java:274)
... 9 more
Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: What are you doing exactly when this exception occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Stating the obvious ... OpenJPA version in use is expecting JPA2, and JBoss 4.x has JPA1 API jar present ... hence the exception that the JPA2 method is not found. Use consistent versions of JPA, and JPA implementation

Comment: thanks it helped... Jpa jar was missing persistence related stuff